# Unable to Join domain, unable to resolve hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, internal-dns

I'm having problems connecting a computer to the domain. I'll explain my setup (with hostnames). I have:

```
 Hyper-V Guest 1 (Imperium) - DC / DNS Server (Server 2016 Essentials)
 Hyper-V Guest 2 (Lima) - Computer I'm trying to add (Server 2016 Standard)
 Desktop Computer (Desktop) - Computer I'm trying to add (Windows 10)
```

I was able to successfully install the DC and DNS roles on the **Imperium** Guest and it seems to have worked fine. When I ping other hosts using hostnames, such as **Lima**, *from the Imperium guest*, it resolves and works. However, when I try to ping the DC host from another Hyper-V Guest (such as **Lima**) the hostname cannot be resolved.  If I ping the DC host from the desktop computer, it works.

From my understanding the reason I'm having problems adding the **Lima** host to the domain is DNS, because it cannot resolve the domain (KBNET.local). So I went into the network connection properties and set the DNS server for the **Lima** guest to the IP address of the DNS server (which is **Imperium**). I still cannot resolve the DC hostname on the Lima Guest. However, I followed the same steps (setting the DNS IP) on the Desktop computer and it can resolve the DC hostname with no problems.

I have tried disabling the Windows firewall with no success. I have also tried adding an entry in the hosts file to resolve the domain (KBNET.local) to the IP address of the DC server which was not successful. All of the machines can ping each other if using IP addresses. Also, the **Lima** guest can ping the hostname of the DC server (**Imperium**), but NOT the domain.

Is there anything else I can try here? Is it possible that there is a communication problem between the DNS server on **Imperium** and **Lima**?

Let me know if I've missed anything. Thanks!

EDIT: Here are some of the things requested:

Adding to Domain Error: http://pastebin.com/zAUsJawF

IP Address Configurations (all computers): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBRp1.jpg

Comment: Attempt the domain join again and then post the error message verbatim in your question. Also post the configuration information for the ip address settings of the clients and Domain Controller.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks for the comment. I've modified the original post to include the error and IP configurations.

Comment: `1.` Get rid of the 192.168.1.1 DNS server on the DC. Add 127.0.0.1 as the secondary DNS server on the DC. `2.` Can you post the output of `ipconfig/all` from the DHCP client?

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks. I removed the 192.168.1.1 from the DC and set it to loopback. Should I reboot anything?

The DHCP client (desktop) ipconfig: http://pastebin.com/pK4QhFUv

Comment: I have figured it out. The difference between the desktop computer and the Lima guest was IPv6 DNS servers. I just disabled IPv6 on the Lima guest and it worked! I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @user393432 Please post your solution as an answer for the benefit of others.